# providing graph view data

Tags: android, graph

Hi i am using sq lite data base in order to draw a graph wit graph view library that i founded in git hub but when lunched the app i got force close!
i am getting data from database as a list and then i want get x and y from my data base for graph.

here is my code:

```
public class lagari_graph extends SherlockFragment {

    List<calery_lagari> Calery_lagari;
    calery_lagari_SQLiteData data;
    calery_lagari Calery_lagaris;
    int i;
    GraphView graphView;
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lagari_graph, null);
        return v;

    }
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        int size = Calery_lagari.size();
        GraphViewData[] data = new GraphViewData[size];
        for (i=0; i<size; i++) {
            Calery_lagaris = Calery_lagari.get(i);
            data[i] = new GraphViewData(i, Calery_lagaris.getcalery());
        }
        GraphViewSeries Series = new GraphViewSeries(data);
        graphView = new LineGraphView(
                getActivity() 
                , "graph" );
        graphView.addSeries(Series);

        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.lin);
        layout.addView(graphView);
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

Log:

```
12-14 19:09:51.242: E/AndroidRuntime(2259): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-14 19:09:51.242: E/AndroidRuntime(2259): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-14 19:09:51.242: E/AndroidRuntime(2259):     at mr.chag.va.lagar.lagari.lagari_graph.onViewCreated(lagari_graph.java:34)
12-14 19:09:51.242: E/AndroidRuntime(2259):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:884)
12-14 19:09:51.242: E/AndroidRuntime(2259):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1080)
12-14 19:09:51.242: E/AndroidRuntime(2259):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:622)
12-14 19:09:51.242: E/AndroidRuntime(2259):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1416)
12-14 19:09:51.242: E/AndroidRuntime(2259):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:431)
12-14 19:09:51.242: E/AndroidRuntime(2259):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:160)
12-14 19:09:51.242: E/AndroidRuntime(2259):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:804)
12-14 19:09:51.242: E/AndroidRuntime(2259):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.completeScroll(ViewPager.java:1280)
12-14 19:09:51.242: E/AndroidRuntime(2259):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.computeScroll(ViewPager.java:1176)
12-14 19:09:51.242: E/AndroidRuntime(2259):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12397)
12-14 19:09:51.242: E/AndroidRuntime(2259):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12453)
12-14 19:09:51.242: E/AndroidRuntime(2259):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13182)
12-14 19:09:51.242: E/AndroidRuntime(2259):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2929)
12-14 19:09:51.242: E/AndroidRuntime(2259):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2799)
12-14 19:09:51.242: E/AndroidRuntime(2259):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12407)
12-14 19:09:51.242: E/AndroidRuntime(2259):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12453)
12-14 19:09:51.242: E/AndroidRuntime(2259):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:2911)
12-14 19:09:51.242: E/AndroidRuntime(2259):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12345)
12-14 19:09:51.242: E/AndroidRuntime(2259):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12453)
12-14 19:09:51.242: E/AndroidRuntime(2259):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:2911)
12-14 19:09:51.242: E/AndroidRuntime(2259):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12345)
12-14 19:09:51.242: E/AndroidRuntime(2259):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12453)
12-14 19:09:51.242: E/AndroidRuntime(2259):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:2911)
12-14 19:09:51.242: E/AndroidRuntime(2259):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12345)
12-14 19:09:51.242: E/AndroidRuntime(2259):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12453)
12-14 19:09:51.242: E/AndroidRuntime(2259):     at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.draw(HardwareRenderer.java:1144)
12-14 19:09:51.242: E/AndroidRuntime(2259):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2147)
12-14 19:09:51.242: E/AndroidRuntime(2259):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2019)
12-14 19:09:51.242: E/AndroidRuntime(2259):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1830)
12-14 19:09:51.242: E/AndroidRuntime(2259):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:998)
12-14 19:09:51.242: E/AndroidRuntime(2259):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4212)
12-14 19:09:51.242: E/AndroidRuntime(2259):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
12-14 19:09:51.242: E/AndroidRuntime(2259):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
12-14 19:09:51.242: E/AndroidRuntime(2259):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
12-14 19:09:51.242: E/AndroidRuntime(2259):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
12-14 19:09:51.242: E/AndroidRuntime(2259):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
12-14 19:09:51.242: E/AndroidRuntime(2259):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-14 19:09:51.242: E/AndroidRuntime(2259):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-14 19:09:51.242: E/AndroidRuntime(2259):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
12-14 19:09:51.242: E/AndroidRuntime(2259):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-14 19:09:51.242: E/AndroidRuntime(2259):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-14 19:09:51.242: E/AndroidRuntime(2259):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
12-14 19:09:51.242: E/AndroidRuntime(2259):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
12-14 19:09:51.242: E/AndroidRuntime(2259):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you hadn't defined the data i mean  `calery_lagari_SQLiteData data;` try to define that in your fragment

```
data =  ......
```